# CSS positioning varies per screen?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to get for instance a logo have a static position on the screen, let say about `40px` from the top and centered horizontally. When I try this, it works. However the positioning varies per screen-size. How can I make this static for all screens?

my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

body{
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
    background-color: #844903;
    }
    .logo{
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    right: 850px;
    }
    h1{
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    right: 720px;
    color: #a86b00;
    }  
    .rf_id{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    }  
    </style>

<title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome, Please scan your studentcard:</h1>

<div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" </a></div>


<button class="rf_id" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent"><a href="index1.5.html"><img src="images/rf_id.jpg" alt="submit"/></a></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will be easier to understand and reply accordingly if we have jsfiddle in front of us

Comment: Take a look at your `<img>` tag. You are not closing it. It has to be this: `<img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />`

Comment: Excuse me what is JSfiddle? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/. here can you paste your code, save it and that share the link so that we can take a look to it.

Comment: @Vinc199789 I altered it, didn't change anything. Thanks though!

Comment: @Vinc199789 http://jsfiddle.net/odwe4s0x/ :)

Comment: Why don't you use percentages? if you have `width:20%;` he is taking always 20% of the width and sets that as width.

Comment: That's a good one, i'll try it out.

Comment: but I have a question. Why don't you use an external css file? That is way more ordened.

Comment: Your question is just. However, I thought this would be a very short single file. Else, I would have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try what's know as 'media query'

This is part of CSS which can set different css to your html according to the screen size.

Example 1:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo{
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    right: 850px;
  }
}
```

This means that if the screen size is less than 600px `.logo` will have the set property.

Example 2:

```
@media all {
  .logo{
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    right: 850px;
  }
}
```

This will set `.logo` to the set property on all screen sizes.

You can use combination of these `media query` to get the desired effect.

Read more about this at:
https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky use pixel to position some elements because in mobile screens there are different density (1x, 2x, 1.5x, ...), so one 1 pixel is not really 1px in a screen with density 2x.

I recommend you use em to layout or if you can, use new css3 sizes: vh and vw.

Comment: Jose: for that I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`. This will fix your problem

Comment: Exactly, I was considering this, But isn't there a way that measures the position parameters according to the actual screen instead of webpage?

Comment: @MieerDarwesh I know you have in Jquery a difference between `$('window').width()` and `$(document).width();`. Window is screen width (so your monitor screen or the width of your browser) and document the width of the site. You can use this to calculate positions

Comment: Yes, another solution could be use css3 media queries with "device-width" property: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html